# ¿Cómo apuntar hacia una base de datos cuando la conexión apunta a otra?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Tengo una aplicación con un *login* que al abrir me apunta una base de datos, esta es mi cadena de conexión:

```
public ConexionBD()
{
    CadenConexion = "Data Source=DESKTOP-38N3PKP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=basededatos;Integrated Security=True";
}   

protected SqlConnection ObtenerConexion()
{
    return new SqlConnection(CadenConexion);    
}
```

Y dentro tengo un form con *TextBox* y un botón para crear una base de datos con el nombre ingresado en el *TextBox*. El código para crear la base de datos que uso es este:

```
public void CrearEmpresa(string nombre)
{
    using(var conexion = ObtenerConexion())
    {
        conexion.Open();
        using(var comando = new SqlCommand())
        {
            comando.Connection = conexion;
            comando.CommandText = "create database " + nombre;
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Con esto creo la tabla:

```
public void CrearTablaDatosEmpresa()
{
    using (var conexion = ObtenerConexion())
    {
        conexion.Open();
        using (var comando = new SqlCommand())
        {
            comando.Connection = conexion;
            comando.CommandText = "create table TablaEmpresa (" +
                "IdEmpresa int identity(1,1) primary key," +
                "RucEmpresa varchar(13)," +
                "RazonSocialEmp varchar(90)," +
                "NombreComercialEmp varchar(90)," +
                "TelefonoEmp1 varchar(14)," +
                "TelefonoEmp2 varchar(14)," +
                "CorreoEmp varchar(50)," +
                "CiudadEmp varchar(25)," +
                "DireccionEmp varchar(150)," +
                "ActividadEconomica varchar(300) )";
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

La base de datos, se me crea, pero al intentar crear una tabla no se me crea en la base de datos que acabo de crear, me dice que ya está creada y efectivamente la tengo creada pero en la base de datos que se muestra en la cadena de conexión.

1. Entonces, ¿Cómo apunto a esa base de datos para que se me creen las tablas?
2. Y al crearse, poder iniciar sesión hacia esa base de datos que acabo de crear.

Comment: Pues la cosa es hacer refactor de la lógica que te permite obtener una conexión a la BD a usar en las consultas, de forma que sigas teniendo la conexión inicial al comienzo pero puedas crear además, otras instancias de Conexion inicializadas con otros parámetros

Comment: @Alfabravo hola, gracias por responder me podrias dar un ejemplo por favor por favor

Comment: También podrías hacer, después del create, un `use Database`, para que el resto de consultas se hagan sobre la última bbdd creada.

Comment: @Jakala olvide comentar eso, hice otro sqlcommand con el use database y no funciona

Comment: otra cosa, podria ser que utilizaras el nombre de la bbdd cuando haces la creacion de la tabla. Seria algo como CREATE TABLE bbdd.tabla... es decir, que el nombre de la tabla este precedido por el nombre de la bbdd...

Comment: @Jakala hice eso y me dice que o no existe o no poseo permisos para el schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez creada tu base de datos deberías pasarle el nombre de la base de datos nueva a la cadena de conexión, siempre entiendo que está en el mismo servidor *SQL*. Una posibilidad sería:

El parámetro con valor te permite que no sea obligatorio pasarlo.

```
public ConexionBD(string db = string.Empty)
{
    CadenConexion = $"Data Source=DESKTOP-38N3PKP\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog={db};Integrated Security=True";
}   

protected SqlConnection ObtenerConexion()
{
    return new SqlConnection(CadenConexion);
}

public void CrearTablaDatosEmpresa(string bd)
{ //ingresar el mismo valor que el textbox habia llenado para crear la base de datos
    using (var conexion = ObtenerConexion(bd))
    {
        conexion.Open();
        using (var comando = new SqlCommand())
        {
            comando.Connection = conexion;
            comando.CommandText = "create table TablaEmpresa (" +
                "IdEmpresa int identity(1,1) primary key," +
                "RucEmpresa varchar(13)," +
                "RazonSocialEmp varchar(90)," +
                "NombreComercialEmp varchar(90)," +
                "TelefonoEmp1 varchar(14)," +
                "TelefonoEmp2 varchar(14)," +
                "CorreoEmp varchar(50)," +
                "CiudadEmp varchar(25)," +
                "DireccionEmp varchar(150)," +
                "ActividadEconomica varchar(300) )";
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, la conexion la tengo en una clase y cuando le agrego lo que me dijiste me aparece esto: 
 
 public class CD_CrearEmpresa:ConexionBD

me dice que no se ha dado ningun argumento que corresponda al parametro requerido

Comment: Debes pasarle el nombre de la base de datos. mira que en el codigo puse $ y la variable entre llaves {} para no tener que andar concatenando con el +

Comment: Entiendo, pero olvide comentar que esa cadena de conexión esta en otra clase dela misma capa de Datos, y cuando hago mi conexion para llamarla cadena la llamo con el dos punto luego del nombre de la clase asi: CD_CrearEmpresa:ConexionBD
Y es ahi donde me dice que se ha dado ningun parametro,como soluciono eso, para que me agarre el parametro que viene del textbox

Comment: Hay que agregar al metodo principa un parametro para que se lo pase a la conexion. Te edito la respuesta.